# Put the code generated by flex to a normal C++ program

Tags: c++, c, bison, yacc, lex

I create a simple file, using flex, it generate a file lex.yy.c, for now, I want to put it to C++ program.

```
%{

 #include < stdio.h>

%}

%%

stop    printf("Stop command received\n");

start   printf("Start command received\n");

%%
```

When I type start or stop in command line, there is a output. What I want to do is to give the input by my C++ program, and the output of it should be sent to a variable in my program, is it possible? Thanks a lot!

I know the code I post is quite simple, but the result I imagine is:

create c file by flex and bison, and I use it as a header, so in the c++ program, I just need to call a function `lex_yacc()` to use it. ex. `lex_yacc()` is a calculator, so I sent an expression with evariables to this function, and it will return the result. I want to use this function in a C++ program, I am confused...Thanks a lot!

Comment: May I also recommend http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428892/what-parser-generator-do-you-recommend and the Lemon parser generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the section about [multiple input buffers](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html) in the manual. Especially the section about `yy_scan_string` and `yy_scan_bytes`.

For the "output", of course the is "output" when you give "stop" or "start" as input, you explicitly do that (i.e. the `printf` calls). You can put any code you want there.